# Forward Floating IP to Internal Port

Tags: linux, networking, ip, centos7, firewalld

I have 3 floating IP: 10.10.1.2 10.10.1.3 and 10.10.1.4 and a physical IP: 10.10.1.1. That 10.10.1.1 have 3 opened ports: 9001, 9002, 9003

Is that possible to forward those floating IP to those ports ? Like 10.10.1.2 will be forwarded to 10.10.1.1:9001, 10.10.1.3 will be forwarded to 10.10.1.1:9002 and 10.10.1.4 will be forwarded to 10.10.1.1:9003.

PS: Using firewalld service on CENTOS7

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

look for answer at [firewall-cmd forward rules for interface with multiple IPs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177096/firewall-cmd-forward-rules-for-interface-with-multiple-ips)

or try something like `firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 destination address=10.10.1.2 forward-port port=1-64000 protocol=tcp to-port=9001 to-addr=10.10.1.1 '`